# Need to join row data into columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've data in below format.

```
ID  GRP VALUE
1   P_1 AA
1   P_2 BB
1   X_1 CC
1   X_2 DD
1   M_1 EE
1   M_2 FF
1   N_1 GG
1   N_2 HH
1   K_1 II
1   K_2 JJ
```

And I need output in below format

```
ID    GRP        PAIRS
1   P_1,P_2      AA,BB
1   X_1,X_2      CC,DD
1   M_1,M_2      EE,FF
1   N_1,N_2      GG,HH
1   K_1,K_2      II,JJ
```

Kindly suggest a sql for this in oracle

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: Do a self join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT
MAX(ID),
LISTAGG(GRP, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUBSTR(GRP, 1, 1)) AS GRP,
LISTAGG(VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SUBSTR(GRP, 1, 1)) AS PAIRS
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY SUBSTR(GRP, 1, 1);
```

I am assuming you want the maximum ID for each group in first column of the output (you wrote all 1s in your example).

Comment: Thanks a ton, This is what I needed

Comment: I think the ordering of the WITHIN GROUP clause should be `ORDER BY SUBSTR(GRP, 3, 1)` to guarantee `X_1,X_2`

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two values, you can use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
select id,
       min(grp) || ',' || max(grp) as grp,
       min(value) || ',' || max(value) as pairs
from t
group by id, substr(grp, 1, 1);
```